# Cant exec () 'python -V' from php. it returns nothing

Tags: python, php

So my problem is that i'm trying to run this python command line to get its version from a php server. I'm using xampp and the .php file is in the htdoc folder. I'm on ubuntu btw and running the command from the terminal works. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$f = exec("python -V" , $f , $d);
var_dump($f);
var_dumb($d);
?>
```

It outputs a blank string array and the error code 127 which means it did not found the command. The output says:

`string(0)""int(127)`

Things i tried was using the absolute path /usr/bin/python -V same result I also tried python3. exec command is not disabled in the php.ini. Does anyone here have any idea on how to make it work.

Comment: can you run this on terminal/cmd `which python`? and share the output

Comment: its /usr/bin/python . yeah sorry there was a typo in the original post, i corrected it

Comment: Oh okay so what happens when you run `$f = exec("/usr/bin/python 2>&1" , $f , $d);` `var_dump($f);` `var_dumb($d);`?

Comment: it says: string(88) "/usr/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/python: undefined symbol: XML SetHashSalt" int(127)

Comment: Oh then it must be an issue with your Python installation it may have been corrupted or a compatibility issue between Python and libraries. Can you remove python entirely and do a fresh install?

Comment: okay i run ubuntu so it came preinstalled with python the only thing i did extra was install updates `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` then i installed  `sudo apt install python3-pip` ,`sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev`. i also installed `sudo apt install python-is-python3` for convinience. Also i tried to simply run a `script.py` with the code `print("Hello world!")` with the terminal `python script.py` and it worked. how would you proceed in cause i have to reinstall everything

Comment: Okay couple of things you can do to debug this would can you if `exec` function is not disabled in your php.ini. Also try using python 3 explicity like `python3 /path/to/your/script.py 2>&1"` in your script. Or else adjust the env path in your PHP script something like this `putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin');`

Comment: python3 did not work same result. exec() is not disabled because i can use commands like `ls` and it will print, it only has problem with python commands. and putting the putenv did nothing